# Главная страница в joomla 1.6

Tags: joomla

Главная страница  в joomla 1.6 выводит статьи блогом. Как сделать чтобы была одна длинная статься без ссылки далее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заходим в меню(главное меню),  выберите пункт меню помеченный главная, там нажимаем на кнопку выбрать напротив тип меню и выбираем нужную статью.

Comment: в шаблоне были баги, поэтому не выводил